# How to combine MSI files created with WiX in differnet languages to one file where yo can select the language?

Tags: localization, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I have a Windows Installer XML (WiX 3.5) project and five localization files for my installer. Therefore WiX creates five .msi files, for every language one. How can i put all in one .msi and let the user select the language when executing the installer?

I heard something about a bootstrapper, but then i would have a Setup.exe and i need a msi file. Is it not possible to adabt the localization strings after compiling with WiX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using transforms. Please take a look at [this article](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/articles/embeddedlang/).

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 parts to making this happen,

- localisation of the Installer UI, and/or
- choice of installed files.

The method I chose will automatically select the local (or near local) language, and can also be forced to a specific transform using command line options.  This doesn't prompt the user to choose which language to install in - so maybe it doesn't actually meet your needs.

The second 'installed files' doesn't seem to be documented as well and I was recently asking about it in [Why would MST not include files with different content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424221/why-would-mst-not-include-files-with-different-content/7449744#7449744).
As a response provided there is now an ANT build script using Windows7 SDK & antdotnet